# will_paginate works on local box, gives "undefined method to_i" on server but both point to the same database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

We just ran into this problem the other day all of a sudden.  Our Rails app is using will_paginate, and I have it defined as follows in my controller:

```
# contacts_controller.rb
def index
  # ...
  @search = @current_user.contacts.search(params[:search])
  @contacts = @search.all.paginate({:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20})
end
```

Both development and staging (this is a staging box not production) point to the same database.  The above code works fine on my local machine, however on staging I get the following error:

`undefined method 'to_i' for {:per_page=>20, :page=>nil}:Hash`

The code is identical on both computers.  Any idea why it works fine on one and not on the other?

EDIT:  On the staging server I was using the plugin while on my local box I was using the gem, however I removed the plugin and installed the gem and now I get an error that says:

`uninitialized constant Array::WillPaginate`

---

Evidently it is still not solved.. after doing a deploy on the staging server I'm getting that error again, despite the fact that it was working before fine.  Anyone have any ideas at all on this?  I'm totally clueless.

Answer (score 0):

If the page param is nil, it's often a good idea to default to a value of 1. This covers cases where no url parameter for page is passed. Where a parameter is passed, it will be used in place of the default:

```
{:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 20})
```

Full example:

```
# contacts_controller.rb
def index
  # ...
  @search = @current_user.contacts.search(params[:search])
  @contacts = @search.all.paginate({:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 20})
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I seem to have solved it:

I had to explicitly type `require 'will_paginate'` in the environment after I uninstalled the plugin and installed the gem.  However I'm still not sure why the plugin was working on my local machine but not on staging.